# Sweden admission deadlines

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, deadlines, sweden

I have researched a few Swedish universities such as Uppsala, Lund, and Stockholm, and the Ph.D. admission deadlines vary a lot. When I go to [ScholarshipDb.net](https://scholarshipdb.net/) and search for positions each has different deadlines too.

I have finished my MSc. in Geography and want to apply for Geography Ph.D. programs. I have a time shortage because in our country six months after graduation the student will face two years of mandatory military service. I am confused right now because there are lots of different deadlines and admission dates.

Are Swedish programs deadlines have a typical norm and are on fixed dates such as U.S. (Nov, Jan, Feb) or they're based on the advertising dates and are somehow unique?

Comment: I don't understand the question, really. Any university that publishes deadlines will adhere to them. If they are all different, then they just are. I don't think this is any different in the US, actually.

Comment: If the Swedish Institutions have published their admission deadlines, which you have obviously found, why do you think there are different dates available?

Comment: The announced positions have different deadlines than the university's deadlines. But typically, in the U.S. they are consistent.

Comment: A supervisor may have sourced funds for a particular post and is now in a position to make the post available which means it will have its own dates for the applications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are Swedish programs deadlines have a typical norm and are on fixed dates such as U.S. (Nov, Jan, Feb) or they're based on the advertising dates and are somehow unique?

The most common way to announce PhD positions is on a case-by-case basis with unique deadlines for each position. **There are no fixed dates that universities have to adhere to**. You will see an increase in the number of available positions during the first quarter of each year since big funding bodies like the Swedish Research Council decide on grants in the fall.

(I'm a PhD student at Karolinska Institutet).